# Using "Go to source" with local Maven projects in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, maven

I'm working within a project that is part of an EAR where all the components are using Maven 2.

I'm trying to use the Navigate -> Go to source function (ctrl+click) in NetBeans 7.1. The class I want to navigate to is located in another project that is also a part of the EAR, and that is currently open in NetBeans as well.

I had expected to navigate to the actual local source file in the project, but instead I'm getting the grey background version that you get when browsing sources attached to a jar.

I realize this is probably exactly what is happening given the way Maven works, but is there a way to make the Navigate -> Go to source function go to the local project source file instead?

Comment: maybe executing 'download library sources' on the maven dependency will solve your issue? Right click in a project explorer, find your war/ear/jar in Libraries folder, right click on it and find some command to download sources (not sure if its there as I'm not a netbeans user anymore)

Comment: @Kris that's not what he wants. He wants to go the source file in the project in Netbeans.

Comment: Have you looked http://wiki.netbeans.org/MavenBestPractices ? If I remember correctly it works like you want with no config what so ever (been a while since I used NB though). Could it be that the versions are not correct, you might depend on an older/never version of the project actually open?

Comment: I just double checked, and the versions match in both the project POM and the root POM that both the projects and the EAR project are members of.

Comment: @Peter I know, I thought that maybe when he download sources for his dependencies (and I guess another project is configured as such) he would be able to see the sources normally

Comment: @Vegard strange.... It's hard to guess a solution without access to your project files....

Comment: @Peter Thankfully it's easy to reproduce. Create two plain Java SE Maven projects in NetBeans, and add one as a dependency to the other. 
Then create a class in the first project, and use it in the second. The dependency is correctly shown as a project, not a jar, but Go to source shows the read only version.

Comment: @Vegard Worked like a charm for me though :(

Comment: @Peter that's strange. Are you using NetBeans 7.1 as well?

Comment: @Vegard NB 7.0.1. I did add the dependency by editing the pom.xml file directly, not using any NB specific functions...

Comment: @Peter That's it. Just tried it in an old NetBeans 7.0.1 install, and there it works as I expected it to. I'll post a bug on the NetBeans bug tracker.Thanks for helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as intended in NetBeans 7.0.1, but not in 7.1.

I've reported this on the Netbeans issue tracker:

http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=208228

Edited for anyone else running into this: The cause was a case sensitive path for  in settings.xml. Make sure you use correct path until a patched version of Netbeans is released.